# UIScroll View will not scroll when items are added

Tags: uiscrollview, xcode4.3, xcode-storyboard

I have a UIScrollView and when I run my app the scroll view works fine.  When I go to add two buttons to the scroll view, on at the bottom and the other at the top, the ability to scroll goes away. I've yet to call any actions to the buttons.  I just wanted to see a scrollview in action

Not sure why this happens.

Here is my code.

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;
}

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[theScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[theScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

change the following Modifications:

**.h**

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
{


   IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller;

}


@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScroller; // Add this Line
```

.**m**

```
**#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize theScroller;  // Add this Line

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [theScroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [theScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 900)];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

**In your XIB;**

1. Set Delegate and link Properly

[image]